# Call to a REST API automatically

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, api

I want to make a request automatically using REST API. The goal is to submit data to an external database automatically by clicking the submit button.
I have this code belllow:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function callApi(){
  var cbIntegrationId = "xxxxxxx"; //Required
  var clientId = "xxxxxx"; //Required
  var clientSecret = "xxxxx"; //Required
  var tableName = "xxxx"; //Required
  var name = "My_Name";

    //Get access token
    $.post(
      "https://" + cbIntegrationId + ".caspio.com/oauth/token",
      {
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: clientSecret
      },
      function(cbAuth){
        //Run POST call
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://" + cbIntegrationId + ".caspio.com/rest/v2/tables/" + tableName + "/records?response=rows",
          type: 'POST',
          'data': JSON.stringify({ "Broker_Code": "Afinidade1004","UniqueID":"988","Drivers_Full_Name":"nome"}), //Define record values
          headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + cbAuth.access_token, //Extracts the access token from the initial authorization call
            "Content-Type": "application/json", //Required, otherwise 415 error is returned
            "Accept": "application/json"
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.Result); //Check the console to view the new added row
          },
          error: function(data) {
            console.log(data.responseJSON); //Check the console to view error message if any
          }
        });
      }
    );
    }
    </script>
```

This is the form but it's not working. Please, I need help.

```
  <form onsubmit="callApi()">
Full Name: 
<input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name"><br>
ID:
<input type="text" name="uniqueID" id="uniqueID"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you elaborate - what does 'Not working' mean? What outcome do you expect, what do you observe? What gets logged? What errors do you see?

Comment: did the page reload? maybe preventing the default `submit` of the form. (`e.preventDefault`)

Comment: @peeebeee I don't see any erros

Comment: What is not working ? Does callApi() is called ? Do you get console.log from success or error ?  Does your `post` hits the target or returns 404 ? Do you really get values from form somehow ? ( now I seee 'xxxxxx' )

Comment: "xxxxxxx" I have this datas

Comment: Please answer our questions - I asked 5, @sonic asked another 5. We're only asking because you haven't given enough information to enable us to help you.